# Option pane stopping the program independently of the choice

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So, I have a JOptionPane and when I click the "red X" of JFrame the confirmation dialog pops out. The problem is that, whatever I choose it stops the programs. How I can NOT stop the program when I click "NO" ?

Also, If I have two frames opened, how I can create it to close just the selected one ? Because it is closing both of the frames.

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to close this window?", "Confirm closing",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fuller code example?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For all we know, you haven't correctly set your JFrame's default exit behavior. Please show your [MCVE] code.

Comment: When I copy that exact code into the start of the `main(..)` method of another class I have open, it works as I'd expect it to, and when selecting 'no' it continues on to launch the other app. So there must be something else going on in code not presented. Post an MCVE as suggested by @JuanCarlosMendoza, so we can spot where your code is going wrong.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I took your point before you edited it, now it just sounds like you're telling me off mate.

Comment: @HomerPlata *"now it just sounds like you're telling me off"* I strongly recommend you grow a thicker skin. If I was telling you off, you'd be in no doubt about it, and the comment could be reported for 'serious problems or moderator attention', which I suggest you do in future. OTOH since you got the message, that comment is noise and has been deleted. Feel free to report this comment if you are offended by it. Also note that while I can choose to delete my own comments, you can also delete yours, for whatever reason you like.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nothing to do with needing a thicker skin, just pointing out your over-reaction. Please feel free to "tell me off and leave me in no doubt", I get the impression you revel in throwing your weight around. Thanks for putting me off contributing in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

then you need to add a WindowListener to your frame like this:

```
 frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to close this window?", "Confirm closing",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

}});
```

And if you have 2 frames but you need to close just one u can use `frame.dispose();` instead of `System.exit(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result of showConfirmDialog by comparing with the appropriate enum (the value returned is not a boolean)

```
int userChoice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to close this window?", "Confirm closing", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
if (userChoice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    window.dispose();
}
```